# Развёртывание REST API (nodejs + express.js) на VPS

Tags: node.js, rest, express, gitlab-ci

Разрабатываю REST API на express.js, локально всё оттестировал, загрузил на VPS и тут появились вопросы:

1. Как можно автоматизировать процесс загрузки и установки сервера?
   Чтобы каждый раз руками не загружать и через консоль не вызывать `npm
   install`.
2. Как запустить сервер, чтобы он работал без консоли? Сейчас, если
   закрыть консоль, то и сервер падает.
3. Как управлять сервером, если надо его остановить/перезапустить?
4. Как отслеживать состояние сервера? Нагрузку, использование ресурсов
   и тд?

Конечно, я почитал про PM2, GitLab CI, но опыта нет, а информации очень много, хотелось бы получить совет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По первому пункту надо смотреть в сторону Continuous Integration. По этому запросу можно найти много информации с примерами.

Вопросы 2-4 как раз решает, например, PM2 (если вы имеете в виду веб-сервер express). Например для запуска приложения можно ввести команду из папки приложения:

```
pm2 start npm --name "myproject" -- start
```

Затем отследить состояние процесса и использование им ресурсов:

```
pm2 list
```

Остановить или перезапустить процесс:

```
pm2 restart myproject
pm2 stop myproject
```

Остальные команды можно посмотреть в документации

Answer (score 1):

1. Какую-нибудь CI использовать. Которая при коммитах сама всё передиплоит.
2. Стартовать под каким-нить супервизором. Мы используем [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/). Если хотите кустарно для тестов, то запускайте ноду через [`nohup`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup):

   ```
   nohup node /путь_до_проекта/index.js &
   ```
3. Через админку, которую предоставляет хостер?
4. Метрики слать. Я на последнем проекте использовал [influx](https://www.influxdata.com/). Самое модное сейчас, наверно, zabbix. Есть сторонние сервисы типо datadog'а.